# Computations with Tensors

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, special-relativity, conservation-laws, stress-energy-momentum-tensor

I have the following ansatz
$$T^{\mu\nu}=AF^{\mu\alpha}F_{\alpha}^\nu+B\eta^{\mu\nu}F^{\alpha\beta}F_{\alpha\beta}$$
for some constants $A,B.$ Here, $F_{\mu\nu}$ is the electromagnetic field tensor, and $\eta^{\mu\nu}$ is the (flat?) metric with signature $(-,+,+,+).$ I need to show that energy and momentum conservation of the EM field (i.e. $\partial_\mu T^{\mu\nu}=0$ for $\nu=0,1,2,3$) implies that $B=A/4$.

The only idea I have is to expand everything and try to eventually compare coefficients. But this is super tedious and unenlightening. Is there a better, smarter approach to this? I am just hoping for a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: Use $F^{\nu}_{\alpha} = \eta_{\alpha \beta} F^{\nu \beta}$ or the same transformation for covariant components. And then do direct computation of derivatives

Comment: A calculation that takes a few lines doesn’t count as “super tedious”.

Comment: *a nudge in the right direction* You have to make use of Maxwell’s equations in covariant form.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula does not make sense. The left-hand side has indices $\mu,\nu$, and the first term of the right-hand side has indices  $\alpha,\nu$.

Comment: indices look fine to me

Comment: Thanks. I had a typo. Corrected now! (Shouldn't that have just been a comment though?)

Comment: @basics : Because the OP edited his/her question a minute before your comment:-)